# How do you add an keyup event listener to window in a React functional component that only gets added when the app originally loads?

Tags: reactjs

First off, here's my code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

function App() {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleKeyUp = (e) => {
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        setCount(count + 1);
      }
    }
    window.document.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp);
    console.log('event listener created.');
    return () => {
      window.document.removeEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp);
      console.log('event listener removed.');
    }
  }, [count, setCount]);

  return (
    <output>Count: {count}</output>
  );
}

export default App;
```

A working copy is at https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-curie-rl0qe.

This code works: pressing Enter increments count. The concern I have is that the listener gets added and removed every time the Enter key is pressed. You can see this in the console. I would like the event listener to be added when the React component initially mounts, and to keep listening until the component unmounts. How would I do that?

**EDIT**

As per the accepted solution, here is the working code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

function App() {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleKeyUp = (e) => {
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
      }
    }
    window.document.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp);
    console.log('event listener created.');
    return () => {
      window.document.removeEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp);
      console.log('event listener removed.');
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <output>Count: {count}</output>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Working copy at https://codesandbox.io/s/react-add-keyup-event-on-win-g23cg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[]` as your effect dependency argument so that it only runs when your component mounts and unmounts. Use the callback method of setting state so that its always using the most recent version of `count` instead of using it as a dependency.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const handleKeyUp = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
    } 
  }

  window.document.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp);

  return () => {
    window.document.removeEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp);
  }
}, []);
```